# Какой лучший и простейший способ сделать предзагрузку данных в tableView?

Tags: swift, coredata, realm

Приветствую!

Возникла необходимость в создании приложения, в котором данные (текст и изображения) уже записаны в базу данных, данные показываются в tableView с последующей возможностью подробно узнать информации при нажатии на ячейку. При этом пользователь может любую ячейку добавлять в другой view controller и, соответственно, другой table view свайпом ячейки влево. Скажите, как можно проще всего реализовать данный функционал? Какой framework стоит использовать? Core Data? Realm? SQLite?

Достаточно сложно найти информацию по предварительному заполнению базы данных при том, что пользователь информацию не может редактировать.

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас есть уже готовая SQLite база данных, просто добавляете ее в проект и работайте с ней. Если понадобится, с легкостью потом и в Android можете ее использовать.

Отличная библиотека для этого: [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Указываете путь/имя, открываете, а дальше уже получаете нужные данные:

```
do {
    let rs = try database.executeQuery("select x, y, z from test", values: nil)
    while rs.next() {
        if let x = rs.string(forColumn: "x"), let y = rs.string(forColumn: "y"), let z = rs.string(forColumn: "z") {
            print("x = \(x); y = \(y); z = \(z)")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```